# How to create a universal library with Xcode 10.2.1?

Tags: ios, xcode, macos

I'm new to creating libraries for iOS (and new to iOS development in general -- I just completed my first "Hello, World" app yesterday) so please don't be afraid to give the long and child-friendly answer.

My goal is to build an SDK which wraps AVPlayer with some business logic and API integration, so that we can distribute this library and our clients can easily create apps that work with my company's video streaming platform.

To get started (learning iOS development, not actually working on the SDK yet) I was following this [iOS static library tutorial by Ray Wenderlich](https://www.raywenderlich.com/2658-creating-a-static-library-in-ios-tutorial). At one point, it mentioned that the library I had just created would only work on the simulator and not a real device, and went on to explain how to create a universal library that would work on both. That's when everything fell apart.

- The link to the documentation for `lipo` 404'd
- The `lipo` man page isn't too helpful in explaining what `lipo` is or what it's supposed to do
- Googling around for `lipo` doesn't seem to turn up much information about it
- Xcode offers the ability to create "cross-platform" targets, as well as an "aggregate" target, making it sound like `lipo` may be deprecated?
- The [Xcode release notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_10_2_release_notes#3141454) seem to hint that `lipo` is ***not*** deprecated
- Copying the "Run Script" build phase from the tutorial I was following caused Clang to throw an error ("i386 is an invalid build target")
- Googling this error, it seems like i386 is accurate for iOS 10 and before, but it's invalid for newer version of iOS?
- I know that iPad Mini (among other devices) cannot be upgraded beyond iOS 9. If I can't build for i386, how do I support these devices?
- Stripping out the `-arch i386` threw an entirely different error: "Unable to attach DB"
- Googling this error I found the suggestion to add `OBJROOT=...` to the run script. This threw ***a different*** error about not being able to load the manifest, and then caused my CPU fan to spin at max speed while Xcode stalled out
- Looking around for other tutorials the vast majority seem to be out-dated, point to menu options or buttons in Xcode that no longer exist, or mention build targets that are not in my list of options

Can someone walk me through exactly how to build a universal library?

Comment: You may want to look into making a `pod`. Check out [CocoaPods](https://cocoapods.org) which is a dependency manager used by thousands of developers and is how companies like Google and Facebook distribute their SDKs to iOS developers. Also see [Creating a CocoaPod](https://guides.cocoapods.org/making/making-a-cocoapod.html)

Comment: @NoodleOfDeath I actually started out looking at CocoaPods, but since it's an extra / third-party tool on top of standard XCode / iOS development, I felt like it made sense to understand how to make a library **in general** before I added any complexity.

Comment: Fair enough; however, I strongly urge you to at least research Cocoapods as it, in my opinion, actually removes complexity by automating the entire packaging and porting to developers processes so that all you have to do is code the classes to your API and developers simply write "pod <yourpodname>" to include your entire framework. Nearly all iOS developers use Cocoapods, including apps like Uber and and Lyft (which use the Google Maps Pod).

Comment: @NoodleOfDeath I just gave CocoaPods a try (after spending a ***lot*** of time trying to build a library in Xcode and getting frustrated, I hoped that CocoaPods would start me off with a "proper" library that I could build from) and ran into immediate issues: https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/8932

Comment: Did you try without using a testing framework? Xcode has a built in one. Also, any particular reason you're developing in Objective-C? Just out of curiosity

Comment: @NoodleOfDeath Our company provides an iOS app written in Objective-C and the clients who requested an SDK (so they can make their own apps) is more familiar with Objective-C. There was actually a long debate among the managers about whether or not it was time to make the switch to Swift, but ultimately it was decided that Swift has undergone too many changes and overhauls so it should be avoided until it's more stable.

Comment: I just tried creating a library ***without*** a test framework and got the same string of errors from CocoaPods as described in the GitHub issue

Comment: I tried creating a CocoaPods library using Swift and received no errors and Xcode opened. So the issue seems to be related to CocoaPod's handling of Objective-C

Comment: Fascinating. Yes, I never had issues when making Swift frameworks. I have not tried making an Objective-C framework. Glad you opened an issue thread on GitHub. That's a major problem.

Answer (score 0):

`lipo` has not been deprecated. It is a tool for manipulating universal (or “fat”) Mach-O files. You can read the `lipo` manual page in Terminal by adding `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/share/man` to your `MANPATH` environment variable and then running `man lipo`.

That Wenderlich tutorial is from 2013. Since iOS 11 (released in 2017), iOS has only supported 64-bit apps and libraries. Is it possible that your deployment target is set to iOS 11 or later? If so, perhaps Xcode recognizes that it should not allow you to build an i386 library for that deployment target.

Try using the `x86_64` architecture instead, if you're willing to target only 64-bit-capable devices and versions of iOS.

Note that the forthcoming Xcode 11 (currently on beta 2 and due for general release around September or October 2019) supports a new `xcframework` format which combines frameworks (or static libraries) for multiple architectures into a single bundle without (directly) using `lipo`. [Harlan Haskins](https://twitter.com/harlanhaskins?ref_src=twsrc%5Egoogle%7Ctwcamp%5Eserp%7Ctwgr%5Eauthor) explains how to create and use xcframework files in [WWDC 2019 Session 416: Binary Frameworks in Swift](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/416/).

Comment: Changing the build target to `iOS 9.3` (because I need to build for iPad Mini, so just changing the architecture to `x86_64` wouldn't work for me) I started getting the database error again: `Accessing build database "/Users/.../XCBuildData/build.db": database is locked Possibly there are two concurrent builds running in the same filesystem location.`

Comment: Changing the architecture from `i386` to `x86_64` and switching the deployment target back to `iOS 12.2` had the same effect. "database is locked"